# Extract json data from StringType Spark.SQL

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, etl

There is hive table with single column of type string.

> ```
> hive> desc logical_control.test1;
> OK
> test_field_1          string                  test field 1
> ```

```
val df2 = spark.sql("select * from logical_control.test1")

df2.printSchema()
```

> ```
> root
> |-- test_field_1: string (nullable = true)
> ```

```
df2.show(false)
```

> ```
> +------------------------+
> |test_field_1            |
> +------------------------+
> |[[str0], [str1], [str2]]|
> +------------------------+
> ```

**How to transform it to structured column like below?**

> ```
> root
> |-- A: array (nullable = true)
> |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
> |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
> ```

I tried to recover it with initial schema that data being structured before it was written to the hdfs. But json_data is null.

```
val schema = StructType(
    Seq(
      StructField("A", ArrayType(
        StructType(
          Seq(
            StructField("S", StringType, nullable = true))
        )
      ), nullable = true)
    )
  )

val df3 = df2.withColumn("json_data", from_json(col("test_field_1"), schema))

df3.printSchema()
```

> ```
> root
> |-- test_field_1: string (nullable = true)
> |-- json_data: struct (nullable = true)
> |    |-- A: array (nullable = true)
> |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
> |    |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
> ```

```
df3.show(false)
```

> ```
> +------------------------+---------+
> |test_field_1            |json_data|
> +------------------------+---------+
> |[[str0], [str1], [str2]]|null     |
> +------------------------+---------+
> ```

Comment: Could you add `desc formatted logical_control.test1;` to the question?

Comment: @Shu

hive> desc logical_control.test1;
OK
test_field_1         string               test field 1        
Time taken: 0.673 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of `test_field_1` is fixed and you don't mind "parsing" the field yourself, you can use an [udf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html) to perform the transformation:

```scala
case class S(S:String)
def toArray: String => Array[S] = _.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","").split(",").map(s => S(s.trim))
val toArrayUdf = udf(toArray)

val df3 = df2.withColumn("json_data", toArrayUdf(col("test_field_1")))
df3.printSchema()
df3.show(false)
```

prints

```
root
 |-- test_field_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- json_data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)

+------------------------+------------------------+
|test_field_1            |json_data               |
+------------------------+------------------------+
|[[str0], [str1], [str2]]|[[str0], [str1], [str2]]|
+------------------------+------------------------+
```

The tricky part is to create the second level (`element: struct`) of the structure. I have used the case class `S` to create this struct.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid parsing the field yourself?

Comment: I didn't find one

Comment: Let me ask you information out of initial question. May be you have some idea about dividing similar structures to few columns before write to hdfs e.g. or some other methods to convenient use the data.

Comment: You could try to write the data to hdfs in a format that supports nested structures (like parquet), so you don't have troubles when reading the data again.